# 'clrscr()' and 'conio.h' not working

Tags: c++, header-files, anjuta

First of all.... I can't include 'conio' in my file (nor 'conio.h') and then I can't use 'clrscr()' in my program...

The code is like this

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio>         \\even 'conio.h' isn't working

main()
{
    clrscr();
}
```

It shows an error like this...

```
/home/myni/Documents/Codes/CPP/Anjuta/src/main.cc:2:16: fatal error: conio: No such file or directory
```

And when I remove the 'conio' header file, it shows something like this...

```
/home/myni/Documents/Codes/CPP/Anjuta/src/main.cc:5:9: error: ‘clrscr’ was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: [conio.h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h) is not part of the C or C++ programming languages. The observed behavior is to be expected.

Comment: Just google what is `conio.h`

Comment: Downvoted for the absence of minimal research effort

Comment: `clrscr` sounds like Turbo C++.  If that's the case, you're learning C++ using outdated material.

Comment: Very outdated material. Every free tutorial in the internet would be better than a book teaching you that.

Comment: Attempting to use backslashes to begin a comment shows a lack of diligence and care. Pay more attention to what you're doing!

Comment: **Learn C++ from a *book*, [preferably one that's not from the late 1980s](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/560648).**

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h):

> conio.h is a C header file used mostly by MS-DOS compilers to provide console input/output.[1] It is not part of the C standard library or ISO C, nor is it defined by POSIX.

In short: Your program is not portable to Unix (or in fact, anything but MSDOS or Win32).

So unless you're using an environment that has this (Microsoft compiler), you'll need to find something else to do console manipulation. I recommend `ncurses` if you need low-level functions to deal with the console.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to run the program on Linux. I did this with Ubuntu some time ago and I think this should work for you.

```
system("clear");
```

This is how I cleared the screen. I hope this helps.